# How can I shorten this javascript expression? document.createElement

Tags: javascript, appendchild, createelement

I would like to shorten this js code, you can?

```
<script>
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = 'file.js';
    h.appendChild(s);
</script>
```

I guess something like this but not work:

```
<script>
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        s = document.createElement('script').type='text/javascript';
    s.src = 'file.js';
    h.appendChild(s);
</script>
```

Comment: You *could* omit the assignment to `type` if you target HTML5-compliant browsers. Otherwise, I'm afraid that code is as short as it will get (barring obfuscation).

Comment: It doesn't work because `s` is being assigned the value of `type` not the whole object.

Comment: you could use `document.head` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]` and you don't need it as a `var h`, simply do `document.head.appendChild(s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frédéric already mentioned above, modern browsers always assume the `<script>` tag to contain JavaScript by default. So you might get away with something like this.

```
(s = document.createElement("script")).setAttribute("src", "/path/to/file.js");
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

The only limitation of this *dirty* implementation is that it doesn't support chaining methods, since setAttribute has no return value.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [document.head](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_head.asp) instead of getElementsByTagName. So:

```
s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = 'file.js';
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

what about this

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
s = document.createElement('script').setAttribute("type", "text/javascript").setAttribute("src","file.js");
h.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: I don't believe this would work. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp setAttribute has no return value - so how can such a chain work?